# Neural Network Architecture for Image to Image Supervised Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, supervised-learning, image-processing

I have a task where I would like to create a supervised learning model where each training record of X,y is a pair of images. e.g. learning a transformation from an image to an image. Is there a standard neural network architecture for such a learning task? I can see hypothetically RNN/Transformers (as a sequence to sequence task), CNNs (due to use of images), or GANs (used for generating images). Ideally something with a published pretrained model I could leverage for transfer learning? Sorry if this is the wrong forum for this sort of question. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see how a GAN would apply. // This is similar to what autoencoders do, construct images (or whatever) from those same images (or whatever).

Comment: hey thanks I think you're right autoencoders make a lot of sense here

Comment: This is not quite an autoencoder, but there are similarities. You will do it wrong if you go grab a Jupyter Notebook with an autoencoder example, though it could be helpful to follow some of the logic for autoencoders.